# how to set textview below view pager inside relatvielayout in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="55dp"
        android:paddingRight="55dp"
        android:paddingTop="55dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/label_businesscard_title"
            android:textColor="#3e4360"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            app:centered="true"
            app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
            app:pageColor="#c6caca"
            app:snap="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp">


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml i want set textview below viewpager and indicator below textview i hae put feature layout below but its not working please suggest me what i m doing wrong. my expected screen is like below.

https://pasteboard.co/GSuVsth.jpg  but not able to do please suggest me.

Comment: not able to understand would u explain me

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/GSvtiPf.png  look current Screen from given XML and expected is https://pasteboard.co/GSuVsth.jpg  please check where am doing wrong @VishalYadav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here try this out I hope it will help you. The problem is you are giving too much padding Top. So either you have to remove that or you have to use **scrollview** and then use this layout to fullfill your requirements or use more space.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="55dp"
    android:paddingRight="55dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
        android:text="@string/label_businesscard_title"
        android:textColor="#3e4360"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:centered="true"
        app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
        app:pageColor="#c6caca"
        app:snap="false" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingLeft="55dp"
android:paddingRight="55dp">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
    android:textColor="#3e4360"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="helllllllllllll"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

   <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:centered="true"
    app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
    app:pageColor="#c6caca"
    app:snap="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingTop="40dp">
```

---

[image]